# I can't use all my RAM!

Tags: memory-usage

I know somebody will mark this as duplicate, but I can't find the answer, so I'm asking.
I have 3GB of RAM and Ubuntu says: Memory 2.9 GiB. No, it is NOT my onboard graphics card, because it uses only ONE GiB of RAM.

Comment: I have a very similar situation; I have 4 GiB installed and 64-bit Kubuntu, and it reports 3.9 GiB.  I always just figured it was "system overhead"; it's still 400 MiB more than I'd get with a non-PAE 32-bit OS.  I'll have to watch this question to see what answer you get.

Comment: What does `free -m` report?

Comment: @ZeissIkon you are messing up too: you probably have 4Gb and NOT 4GiB. Memory is NOT sold as GiB. 4Gb is roughly 3.9GiB.

Comment: If you respond with the brand and model of your pc (probably laptop), I believe I can provide the solution the rest of this mystery.  I'm guessing you have a netbook with 1gb soldered down,  2gb plugged in, and a video display chipset which borrows from your system RAM.

Comment: @Rinzwind, no, memory *is* sold in GiB

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.  If you had 3 GB and 1 was used for graphics, then that would leave you with only 2, not 2.9.

Comment: @psusi I wish https://www.google.nl/search?q=memory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=gKmjVKLLAsurUeDKgqAL#q=RAM+computer+64Gb ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind RAM has been manufactured and sold in powers of 2 since before I bought my first chips (to be seated in sockets, in banks of 9 to make a 16 KiB page with parity -- upgrading a computer with 16 KiB to 64 KiB).  The methods of manufacture and addressing scheme make powers of two the most practical way to deal with this.  Mass storage devices, OTOH, have been sold in powers of ten since long before gigabyte drives came out (my first hard disk was 20 MB, and held just under 20 MiB).

Comment: @Rinzwind, I have no idea what you meant or why you posted that link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1GB (1 Gigabyte = 1'000 MB) and 1GiB (1 Gibibyte = 1'024 MiB) aren't the same thing.

You say that you should have 3GB of RAM and the Graphics chip uses 1 GiB.

I assume you have a total of 4GB RAM, of which 1GiB is dedicated the Graphics chip. And what's the result of 4GB-1GiB? That's correct: 2.9GB or 2.73GiB.

I've got the slight feeling that even memory manufacturers don't know the difference between those two unit systems (or they deliberately fool the customers and use them interchangably, so your 4GiB memory actulally only is 4GB, which is 3.72GiB) That Ubuntu says 2.9GiB doesn't sound correct to me. Frontends and their system utils don't always 100%ly match...

So you see, it's always a fuss about those two unit systems. Better not think about it and accept it or you'll end up with a terrible headache...

Comment: +1 you beat me to this answer.  An auto calculator and chart can be found here if the OP, or anyone else, wants more info.... http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html

Comment: This needs a little more digging; HD manufacturers tend to go by GB, but RAM manufacturers go by GiB ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion)). I agree the difference is probably negligible, but I'm not positive this is the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed, only HD manufacturers use powers of 10, ram is in powers of 2, so 4 GB of ram is 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 bytes.

Comment: RAM has always been in powers of 2.  Google "GB RAM" and you'll find multiple listings of modules as containing 1024 Megabytes; in fact, megabyte originally referred to 1024 * 1024 bytes, and it was false advertising by hard disk makers that brought up the need to distinguish between MB and MiB.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, to be fair, floppy makers also screwed it up, adding to the confusion.  720k disks were 720 KiB, but when they doubled the density to 1440 KiB, they mislabeled them as 1.44 MB, which isn't correct using *either* base 2 or base 10.